# Weighting the singular values by a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthonormal

The SVD of the matrix $A\in \mathbb{C^{M\times N}}$ is $A=U\Sigma V^H$ where $U \in \mathbb{C}^{M\times M}, V \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ and $\Sigma$ is diagonal with the diagonal elements as the singular values ($\sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2, ..., \sigma_m^2$). Let $P$ be a linear transformation constructed by having the last $N-1$ columns of $V$ as its columns. 
Since the columns of $V$ represents an orthonormal basis, the multiplication $AP$ has the effect of zeroing the first singular value of $A$.

My goal is to zero the first singular value $\sigma_1^2$ and weight the next two ($\sigma_2^2, \sigma_3^2$) by factors $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. I can achieve that by multiplying the first two columns of $P$ by $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. Therefore the multiplication $AP$ has the effect of weighting the second and third singular values, i.e, $\alpha_1 \sigma_2^2, \alpha_2 \sigma_3^2$. However $P$ no longer has orthonormal columns since the first two columns are weighted by $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ . I'm looking for a transformation $P$ that has the same effect of weighting the singular values, but with orthonormal columns. Does this kind of transformation exist. Secondly, is there any square matrix that can achieve the same result, it has to be non-orthogonal as square orthogonal matrices don't change the frobenius norm.

Comment: I guess you mean multiplying first columns of $V$ by $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ and letting that form $P$ (which would make it square), and I think you don't want squares on the singular values.

Comment: Also don't quite understand your goal. Do you want $AP$ to behave like $A$ except a different weighting?  In that case if $W$ is the $N \times N-2$  matrix with the last $N-2$ columns of $V$, then wouldn't you want $P=WW^H$?  In the reweighted case, then you would have $VDV^H$ where $D$ is diagonal with $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,1,\ldots,$

Comment: @Evan $P$ is rectangular with dimensions $N \times N-2$ How would the choice $P=WW^H$ give $VDV^H$. I want a transformation that would weight the first two singular values of $A$ by $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, and hopefully has orthonormal columns or if not, a full matrix.

Comment: Let me clarify: You want a $P$ such that $AP$ does what? Note your current $AP$ (that zeros two singular values), is a map from $\mathbb{R}^{N-2} \to \mathbb{R}^N$.  As you have written now, multiplying the first two columns of $P$ won't bring back the other two singular values. You would have to let $P$ be $V$, and /then/ multiply the first two columns by the scalars.

Comment: @Evan You are right $P$ is $N\times N-1$. I want to zero the first singular value and weight the second and third by $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. I edited the question.